# Applying LSTM and CNN for text classification and comparison?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have applied LSTM and CNN separately [here](https://github.com/Ishaan28malik/Text-Classification-) and got the results simultaneously.

For [data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection) data set.
But I am looking for a solution where I can apply both of them simultaneously together and hence produce a result that will compare them and give an accurate visualization of the result.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/).

Comment: Any other useful resources you know?